# I can't summon during the quest 'engaging the empire'

Tags: final-fantasy-15

I've played this quest around 5 times and not once has it told me that I can summon, I've tried pressing the summon button anyway, but it doesn't work. Looking at videos of the quest, it seems you need to summon to complete it, but it's not working for me. Does anyone know how to fix this or if I may be doing anything wrong?

Comment: Be sure to hold the button down as well, for me L2, hold it till the summon starts.

Answer (score 1):

The ability to summon (in this case Ramuh), is available when Noctis is not being attacked.

You'll have to move to a safe-ish area not too far from the action and activate the summon. You'll know a summon is available because the button to do so appears on the lower left of the screen under the Technique Gauge.